# Windows: automated archiving of pdf files after use.

Tags: windows, pdf, ftp

Any help on this would be much appreciated; Here is my situation.

I am running some pdf software on the ipad which talks to my FTP server here and grabs files.  I have students submitting files to teachers ready for marking,  so the file gets put into a Submissions folder on my FTP.  The teachers can then access it on their ipad software (PDF Expert) and mark the content, and send back to the student (it gets put into a marked folder which the student can then see).

The trouble is I need the submissions to be deleted/archived when they are sent to the marked folder otherwise the teachers don't know which files have been marked.

I am using Xstarter to run automated tasks which send emails out to teachers and students when files have changed/been uploaded.  Perhaps there is a way I can script a task which can monitor the submissions folder and the marked folder and archive the file once it has been uploaded?.. I am really stumped :s

or perhaps a button in a pdf could be coded to move the file to a directory?

Best regards,